# New to JSON, what can I do with this json response

Tags: javascript, json

A website returns the following JSON response, how would I consume it (in javascript)?

```
[{"ID1":9996,"ID2":22}]
```

Is JSON simply returning an array?

Comment: What platform are you using to consume it? Is this javascript code on a web page, or some other type of application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use:

```
function evalResponse(response) {
    var xyz123 = null;
    eval("xyz123 = " + response);
    return xyz123;
}
```

An alternative method is to simply use:

```
var myObj = eval(response);
```

Basically, you have to call `eval()` on the response to create a javascript object. This is because the response itself is just a string when you get it back from your AJAX call. After you `eval` it, you have an object that you can manipulate.

```
function myCallback(response) {
    var myObj = evalResponse(response);
    alert(myObj.ID1);
}
```

You could use a javascript library to handle this for you. Or, you could try to parse the string yourself. `eval()` has it's own problems, but it works.

Comment: upvote for the trick using an extra assignment to stop some security vulnerabilities: if it's not assignable, the eval will just fail.

Comment: Thanks. It can still be worked around, but it's an extra level for a malicious user to worry about.

Comment: Despite having worked around it, the eval() approach is not a good thing to be teaching due to the security problems. There are many dedicated JSON parsers including the canonical one at json.org, and JSON parsers are also being integrated into web browsers and the upcoming ECMAScript standard. I would much rather see a JSON parser used than eval().

Comment: Yes. A JSON parser would be better.

Answer (score 7):

If you use http://www.JSON.org/json2.js you can use it's method JSON.parse to retrieve the json *string* as an object (without the use of eval (which is considered evil)), so in this case you would use:

```
var nwObj = JSON.parse('[{"ID1":9996,"ID2":22}]');
alert(nwObj.ID1); //=> 9996
```

Comment: Upvoted; this is the only answer which actually recommends use of the JSON parser library rather than the insecure eval().

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an array with a single object holding two properties.  I'd much prefer to see the same data structured like this:

> {"ID":[9996,22]}

Then you have a single object holding an array with two elements, which seems to be a better fit for the data presented.  Then using Endangered's `evalResponse()` code you could use it like this:

```
var responseObj = evalResponse(response);

// responseObj.ID[0] would be 9996, responseObj.ID[1] would be 22
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers might not answer your question, maybe you're looking for a way to use that "array of 1 object". Maybe this can help:

```
var arr = [{"ID1":9996,"ID2":22}];
var obj = arr[0];
var id1 = obj.ID1;
var id2 = obj.ID2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you get to your data:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var something = [{"ID1":9996,"ID2":22}]
alert(something[0].ID1)
</script>
```

Comment: That doesn't include the response.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you posted represents an array containing one object, which has attributes ID1 and ID2 (initialized to the respective values after the colon).

To convert the string to a javascript object, pass it to eval, like this:

```
var obj = eval('[{"ID1":9996,"ID2":22}]');
```

However, this method will fail if you only have a single object instead of an array, so it is safer to wrap it in parenthesis:

```
var obj = eval('(' + jsonResponse + ')');
```